# Airwatch SDK iOS - We were unable to retrieve the configuration information

Tags: ios, swift, airwatch, airwatchsdk

Using the **Airwatch SDK v21.4 on iOS** an error is shown:

> "We were unable to retrieve the configuration information. Press
> continue to try again"

Using Airwatch SDK 20.9 worked fine, but after upgrading to version (21.0 thru 21.4) on iOS the SDK is displaying the error.

The message text can be found in an AWSDK.framework file Localizable.strings within the entry RetryToFetchConfigurationInformation

I can do a fresh install from the HUB app just fine.

After launching the app the UI is not displayed until a successful response from controllerDidFinishInitialCheck.

My `controllerDidFinishInitialCheck` method does not contain any errors.
After receiving a valid controllerDidFinishInitialCheck result the UI is displayed, followed by a popup alert message with the error.

Advice / Suggestions / How can I isolate this issue? It may be a timeout issue?